# Create a completed Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm implementing a method `Task<Result> StartSomeTask()` and happen to know the result already before the method is called. How do I create a [Task<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) that has  already completed?

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
private readonly Result theResult = new Result();

public override Task<Result> StartSomeTask()
{
    var task = new Task<Result>(() => theResult);
    task.RunSynchronously(CurrentThreadTaskScheduler.CurrentThread);
    return task;
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Note, the answers to this question also work just fine for creating a plain Task (no <T>) because Task<T> inherits from Task.

Comment: Note that today there's `ValueTask` for completed tasks (i.e. for values you already have so that code is essentially synchronous), which will save you an allocation.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
private readonly Result theResult = new Result();

public override Task<Result> StartSomeTask()
{
    var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();
    taskSource.SetResult(theResult);
    return taskSource.Task;
}
```

Comment: @DanielLobo you might get an answer if you explain what your objection is

Comment: Shouldn't it be the one below that is simpler and with a lot more up votes?
@user2023861

Answer (score 229):

When targeting .NET 4.5 you can use [`Task.FromResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx):

```
public static Task<TResult> FromResult<TResult>(TResult result);
```

To create a failed task, use [`Task.FromException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception.aspx):

```
public static Task FromException(Exception exception);
public static Task<TResult> FromException<TResult>(Exception exception);
```

.NET 4.6 adds [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask.aspx) if you need a non generic `Task`.

```
public static Task CompletedTask { get; }
```

---

Workarounds for older versions of .NET:

- When targeting .NET 4.0 with Async Targetting Pack (or AsyncCTP) you can use `TaskEx.FromResult` instead.
- To get non-generic `Task` prior to .NET 4.6, you can use the fact that `Task<T>` derives from `Task` and just call `Task.FromResult<object>(null)` or `Task.FromResult(0)`.

Comment: To return a non generic task, it's better to use something like Task.FromResult(0).  Using "null" as parameter can confuse compiler which cannot determine the generic parameter.

Comment: What about exceptions? Async methods are compiled into state machine that catches exceptions and saves them in the returned Task. This happens even for code executing before first await. Method returning Task.FromResult might throw exceptions directly.

Comment: @RobertVažan An interesting edge case. Arguably, if you are retrieving your _known result_ from a method and that method throws exceptions then there is a defect that needs fixing.

Comment: @RobertVažan You can easily write your own `FromException` method, that behaves like `FromResult` but instead represents a faulted task.  Such a method can simply return that for its error cases if it's important for the exception to be represented in the resulting task.

Comment: Task.FromException is not available in .NET 4.5... I think it should be specified.

Answer (score 11):

For tasks with no return value, .NET 4.6 has added [Task.CompletedTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask.aspx).

It returns a task which is already in state `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`. It probably returns the same instance every time, but the documentation warns you not to count on that fact.

Comment: given the question specifically refers to `Task<T>` this would be best as a comment

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rx, an alternative is Observable.Return(result).ToTask().

Answer (score 1):

Calling Task.WhenAll without any parameters will return a completed task.

```
Task task = Task.WhenAll();
```

Comment: while this will work, it an obscure workaround that might confuse people when reading the code as it implies waiting for tasks that don't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can try `var myAlreadyCompletedTask = Task.FromResult<string>("MyValue")`
This will give you a task with a specified return type