# Correct way to create a task with a result already ready

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Sometimes I create a method like this

```
Task<int> f()
{
    if (...) return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 42); // in this case, result already known
    else ... // return some "real task"
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to create a task thas is already completed, so that I won't incur any potential overhead of scheduling the "calculation" 42

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a completed Task<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245968/create-a-completed-taskt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
tcs.SetResult(42);
return tcs.Task;
```

(via [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/10/07/10072980.aspx))

Comment: Thanks. I hoped there was a simpler solution. 
Maybe I'll make one such as: public static Task<T> CreateCompletedTask(T t) {...}