# If my interface must return Task what is the best way to have a no-operation implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, threadpool

In the code below, due to the interface, the class `LazyBar` must return a task from its method (and for argument's sake can't be changed). If `LazyBar`s implementation is unusual in that it happens to run quickly and synchronously - what is the best way to return a No-Operation task from the method?

I have gone with `Task.Delay(0)` below, however I would like to know if this has any performance side-effects if the function is called a *lot* (for argument's sake, say hundreds of times a second):

- Does this syntactic sugar un-wind to something big?
- Does it start clogging up my application's thread pool?
- Is the compiler cleaver enough to deal with `Delay(0)` differently?
- Would `return Task.Run(() => { });` be any different?

Is there a better way?

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyAsyncTest
{
    internal interface IFooFace
    {
        Task WillBeLongRunningAsyncInTheMajorityOfImplementations();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An implementation, that unlike most cases, will not have a long-running
    /// operation in 'WillBeLongRunningAsyncInTheMajorityOfImplementations'
    /// </summary>
    internal class LazyBar : IFooFace
    {
        #region IFooFace Members

        public Task WillBeLongRunningAsyncInTheMajorityOfImplementations()
        {
            // First, do something really quick
            var x = 1;

            // Can't return 'null' here! Does 'Task.Delay(0)' have any performance considerations?
            // Is it a real no-op, or if I call this a lot, will it adversely affect the
            // underlying thread-pool? Better way?
            return Task.Delay(0);

            // Any different?
            // return Task.Run(() => { });

            // If my task returned something, I would do:
            // return Task.FromResult<int>(12345);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test();
        }

        private static async void Test()
        {
            IFooFace foo = FactoryCreate();
            await foo.WillBeLongRunningAsyncInTheMajorityOfImplementations();
            return;
        }

        private static IFooFace FactoryCreate()
        {
            return new LazyBar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245968/create-a-completed-task

Comment: Personally I'd go with `Task.FromResult<object>(null)`.

Answer (score 797, accepted):

Today, I would recommend using [Task.CompletedTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask.aspx) to accomplish this.

---

Pre .net 4.6:

Using `Task.FromResult(0)` or `Task.FromResult<object>(null)` will incur less overhead than creating a `Task` with a no-op expression.  When creating a `Task` with a result pre-determined, there is no scheduling overhead involved.

Comment: And if you happen to be using https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx they provide a TaskConstants class to provide these completed tasks along with several other quite useful ones (0 int, true/false, Default<T>())

Comment: `return  default(YourReturnType);`

Comment: @Legends That doesn't work for creating a Task directly

Comment: im not sure but `Task.CompletedTask` might do the trick! (but requires .net 4.6)

Comment: Can `CompletedTask` be used like `Task.FromResult<string>("foo");` and if so how?

Answer (score 205):

To add to [Reed Copsey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13127229/885318) about using `Task.FromResult`, you can improve performance even more if you cache the already completed task since all instances of completed tasks are the same:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static readonly Task CompletedTask = Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

With `TaskExtensions.CompletedTask` you can use the same instance throughout the entire app domain.

---

The [latest version of the .Net Framework (v4.6)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2015/02/02/new-task-apis-in-net-4-6.aspx) adds just that with the [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask.aspx) static property

```
Task completedTask = Task.CompletedTask;
```

Comment: Do I need to **return** it or **await** on it?

Comment: @Pixar what do you mean? You can do both, but awaiting it will continue synchronously.

Comment: Sorry, I had to mention the context :)
As I see it now, we can make `public Task WillBeLongRunningAsyncInTheMajorityOfImplementations()` as well as `public async Task WillBeLongRunningAsyncInTheMajorityOfImplementations()`. So, we can either `return CompletedTask;` or `await CompletedTask;`. What is more preferrable (maybe more efficient or more congruent)?

Comment: @Pixar no async would be more efficient. And anyways, if you do choose async then you don't need a completed task to begin with (`async Task DoAsync() { }`);

Comment: So, that should be the answer to the Jon's question?

Comment: @Pixar I wan't clear. I meant "'no-async' would be more efficient". Making a method async instructs the compiler to transform it into a state-machine. It will also create a new task each time you call it. Returning an already completed task would be clearer and more performant.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would caching the resolved task affect performance?

Comment: @Asad it reduces allocations (and with it GC time). Instead of allocation new memory and constructing a Task instance each time you need a completed Task, you only do this once.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy [it doesn't](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,11a386e7d7cae64a) and it can't, that will basically be a memory leak as it can't know how many possible values it may receive. Caching 2 tasks for `true` and `false` is fine, but caching 4 billion for `int` is quite problematic.

Comment: @i3arnon it's not done yet, but [it will be implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7798).

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy 1. That's a different API. `Task.FromResult` will still not cache. 2. It's a suggestion, it doesn't mean it will be implemented.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I have. There is zero chance `Task.FromResult` will cache everything. It will **maybe** cache a few common values like `true`, `false`, `0` and some other default values.

Comment: Better to call this TaskConstant as it'll clash with System.Threading.Tasks.TasksExtensions.

Answer (score 45):

`Task.Delay(0)` as in the accepted answer was a good approach, as it is a cached copy of a completed `Task`.

As of 4.6 there's now `Task.CompletedTask` which is more explicit in its purpose, but not only does `Task.Delay(0)` still return a single cached instance, it returns the **same** single cached instance as does `Task.CompletedTask`.

The cached nature of neither is guaranteed to remain constant, but as implementation-dependent optimisations that are only implementation-dependent as optimisations (that is, they'd still work correctly if the implementation changed to something that was still valid) the use of `Task.Delay(0)` was better than the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm still using 4.5 and when I did some research I was amused to find that Task.Delay(0) is special cased to return a static CompletedTask member. Which I then cached in my own static CompletedTask member. :P

Comment: I don't know why, but `Task.CompletedTask` can't be used in PCL project, even if I set the .net version to 4.6 (profile 7), just tested in VS2017.

Comment: @Fay I'd guess it must not be part of the PCL API surface, though the only thing do anything with at the moment that supports PCL also supports 4.5 so I'm already having to use my own `Task.CompletedTask => Task.Delay(0);` to support that, so I don't know for sure off the top of my head.

Answer (score 37):

```
return Task.CompletedTask; // this will make the compiler happy
```

Comment: `return` didn't work for me - for an `async` Task, I had to just use `await Task.CompletedTask`.

Comment: @dylanh724 I think it depends on your function definition, the original question requires returns something, so `return Task.CompletedTask` should help. However, if your function definition prob return void, then you can `await`

Answer (score 29):

Recently encountered this and kept getting warnings/errors about the method being void.

We're in the business of placating the compiler and this clears it up:

```
    public async Task MyVoidAsyncMethod()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

This brings together the best of all the advice here so far.  No return statement is necessary unless you're actually doing something in the method.

Comment: That is completely wrong. You are getting a compiler error because the method definition contains async, so the compiler expects an await. The "correct" usage would be public Task MyVoidAsyncMethog() { return Task.CompletedTask;}

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted as this seems to be the cleanest answer

Comment: Because of Keith's comment.

Comment: He isn't totally wrong, he's just removed the async keyword. My approach is more idiomatic. His is minimalistic. If not a bit rude.

Comment: This makes no sense, completely agree with Keith here, I don't get all the upvotes actually. Why would you add code that is not necessary? `public Task MyVoidAsyncMethod() {}` is completely the same as above method.

If there is a usecase for using it like this, please add the additional code.

Comment: My usecase was 'public async Task MyVoidAsyncMethod()
    { #if !DEBUG ..DoStuff ... #endif
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }'

Comment: To avoid the void warning. Unless they've updated the compiler to stop doing this.

Answer (score 15):

When you must return specified type:

```
Task.FromResult<MyClass>(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the `Task completedTask = Task.CompletedTask;` solution of .Net 4.6, but another approach is to mark the method async and return void:

```
    public async Task WillBeLongRunningAsyncInTheMajorityOfImplementations()
    {
    }
```

You'll get a warning (CS1998 - Async function without await expression), but this is safe to ignore in this context.

Comment: If your method returns void, you can have issues with exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using generics, all answer will give us compile error. You can use `return default(T);`. Sample below to explain further.

```
public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(string id)
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = await this._container.ReadItemAsync<T>(id, new PartitionKey(id));
                    return response.Resource;
                }
                catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {

                    return default(T);
                }

            }
```

Comment: The question wasn't about async methods :)

Answer (score -1):

```
return await Task.FromResult(new MyClass());
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.