# Asynchronous method that does nothing

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have an interface `IAnimation` which exposes a method `BeginAsync()`. That method should start the animation and return when it is completed.

What I would like to do is implement a `null` animation class `NoAnimation` that just returns when it executes `BeginAsync()`.

Is this the right implementation?

```
public async Task BeginAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { });
}
```

I suspect that there is a more elegant approach than this. I also considered 
creating an empty method. But that gives me a warning which I don't like either.

Comment: Related: [Create a completed Task](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14244114/1497596)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If my interface must return Task what is the best way to have a no-operation implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127177/if-my-interface-must-return-task-what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-no-operation-imp)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just use [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx) to return a completed task:

```
public Task BeginAsync()
{
     return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

If you have a `Task<TResult>` use [`Task.FromResult<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx) to return a completed task with a result:

```
public Task<bool> BeginAsync()
{
     return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Your current implementation is very inefficient, as it builds the state machine, and also uses a ThreadPool thread to run the empty task.

Comment: First method should be: `await Task.CompletedTask;`. Second method should be `return await Task.FromResult(true);` In addition tey require the async key. Please, fix your code

Comment: @GianpieroCaretti No, that is absolutely bad advice. Using `await` when it is not needed adds zero benefit and extra overhead. What I have is correct.

Comment: Should be noted that this property only available in .net 4.6+

Comment: is there a one liner for this?

Comment: @coolbreeze `Task.CompletedTask` and `Task.FromResult` are both already one liners...?

Comment: @coolbreeze In C# 6.0+ (released in July 2015, so some time after you originally asked) you can now make the whole method a one liner, with `public Task BeginAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;`

Comment: That is not the correct answer. The question asked how to do with an 'async' function. This answer answers to a function without 'async'. Regardless of efficiency, that's not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this doesn't exactly answer the original question (or at least not in a way that isn't already in another answer). What it does it provide additional context for @ReedCopsey's answer, for those (including me! and others, based on the comments on that answer) who initially might find it hard to understand what is going on here.

---

It's very easy to fall into the trap of thinking that `async` must be part of the signature of any asynchronous method. It looks as if it must be; it (misleadingly!) reads as if it's whole purpose is to mark a method as asynchronous.

But it's not, `Task` or `Task<T>` are required, but not `async`. This is shown in @ReedCopsey's answer and in the following correct example (slightly adapted from [this useful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232675/795690)):

```
public Task<int> MethodTaskAsync(int arg0, int arg1)
{
    Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() => Method(arg0, arg1));
    task.Start(); // Hot task (started task) should always be returned.
    return task;
}
```

That's why interface method signatures don't need, and can't have, the `async` keyword: an 'asynchronous' method per se, without regard to how it might be implemented, is *just* a method that returns a started (and, possibly, already finished) `Task` or `Task<T>`.

If `async` doesn't mark a method as asynchronous, what does it do? It's a way to write asynchronous methods more simply: once you have applied it to a method, you can use the `await` keyword to tell the compiler to correctly handle subsidiary asynchronous calls for you very simply (without it, you could try to handle subsidiary `Task`s manually, using lots more code like that in the code block above, but to do so would be very complex and error prone).

So if you just want to return a do-nothing, already-completed task from an 'asynchronous' (i.e. `Task`-returning) method, you can and should do so synchronously(!), as in @ReedCopsey 's answers, using `Task.CompletedTask` or `Task.FromResult(...)`.