# OWIN Authentication:async method lacks 'await' operators

Tags: c#, .net, owin

I have implemented OWIN authentication in my project.But when I try to build the project, it is showing some errors.

The methods which are showing errors :

```
 public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
    //code    
   }
  public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
  //code 
    }
```

The showing error is

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please show us the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using an `await` operator in the implementation of the function then you can remove the `async` modifier.

However, once you remove it, the compiler will expect you to provide a return value for `Task`. You can obviously create a `Task` however you choose, but in this instance you might want to just return the following (which is [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127177/if-my-interface-must-return-task-what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-no-operation-imp)):

```
public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`async` is *not* part of the signature. Just because you're overriding an `async` method doesn't mean that you have to mark your override as `async`.

So, if you don't have any `await`s in your code, just remove the `async` mark.

```
public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
//code    
}
public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
//code 
}
```

Comment: But when I removed the async from method signature, it is showing an error 'not all code paths return a value'