# Implement Async Interface synchronous

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

Assume i have the following interface:

```
public interface IApiOutputCache
{
    Task RemoveStartsWithAsync(string key);
    Task<T> Get<T>(string key) where T : class;
    Task RemoveAsync(string key);
    Task<bool> ContainsAsync(string key);
    Task Add(string key, object o, DateTimeOffset expiration, params string[] dependsOnKeys);
    Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAllKeys();
}
```

I can implement different cache providers. I implemented it twice for two different caches:

a) azure redis
b) memory cache

For azure redis this works absolutely fine since StackExchange.Redis offers all the async methods for me so i can stay completely async.

Now i implement another one for the memory cache which does not offer async api for me.
**Now what is the best pratice to implement this interface?**
Implement it as is but just do everything sync? Warp the internal calls to a `Task.Run` (not a good idea for fast mem cache calls i think).

Comment: I agree with your suggestion. Alternatively, you could run everything synchronously and return  Task.FromResult to make it look like it's asynchronous.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Forget about `Task.Run`, there's no need to offload anything to the `ThreadPool`.

Implement everything synchronously and return an already completed `Task` with `Task.FromResult` when returning a value and `Task.CompletedTask` when not:

```
Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
{
    T result = Get(key);
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}

Task RemoveAsync(string key)
{
    Remove(key);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Or even better, since it's a cache you can cache the tasks themselves instead of the results and return the same task object every time.

Comment: Thanks. Okey that was the way i supposed. But what is Task.CompletedTask? It is new in .net 4.6 right? how does it differ from Task.FromResult(0)?

Comment: Yes, it's new in .Net 4.6. It's slightly better because it returns the same instance every time instead of allocating a new task each call. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26226195/885318