# How do you handle a 3rd party interface returning Task if you don't have any async code?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, synchronous

I am working with a third-party dll which exposes methods which return `Task` and `Task<T>`. I don't have any control over this assembly or the interface, and I assume the author assumed everything would need to be async since the naming of the methods are *Async() as shown below.

Given that, how do I properly implement the interface if I don't actually have any asynchronous code running?

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Task DoWorkAsync();

    Task<int> GetValueAsync();
}
```

---

My attempt was the following:

```
public class FooBar : IFoo
{
    public async Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        // Do Some Work

        await Task.Yield();
    }

    public async Task<int> GetValueAsync()
    {
        // Do Some Work
        var result = ...;

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Additionally:

- Was the author correct in exposing only methods that returned `Task`/`Task<T>`?
- Was the author correct in suffixing method names with *Async()? Code analysis doesn't complain if I write an async method without appending **Async** to the name.

Comment: I'd say yes on calling methods `Async`. Makes it clear and simple, esp. when you're upgrading and trying to keep things backwards compatible to have methods `GetSomething` and `GetSomethingAsync`.

Comment: I generally do the former of your two approaches.  If there's nothing to await then there's nothing to await.  Seems unnecessary, but 3rd party libraries are what they are.

Comment: @David: There aren't two approaches shown, those are two different methods, one of which technically doesn't have a return, which is why it is just `Task` instead of `Task<T>`.

Comment: @michael: And of those two methods I usually use the approach taken in the first method, simply awaiting `Task.Yield()`.  Whether or not you want to do that in the second method is I guess your personal preference.  I'd be interested to know if there's any real benefit in one over the other, but I doubt there's any discernible difference.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932391/implement-async-interface-synchronous. These address the technical question of how to implement an interface like this when your own code isn't inherently asynchronous. If you are asking how one _should_ do it, that is primarily opinion based and too broad a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have async work to do don't include the `async` keyword. Your `GetValueAsnyc` function was almost correct, you just needed to drop the `async`. For your `DoWorkAsync` you should just not mark the method async and return a completed task.

```
public class FooBar : IFoo
{
    public Task DoWorkAsync()
    {
        // Do Some Work

        //If you can use .NET 4.6
        return Task.CompletedTask;

        //For older versions, the thing you pass in does not matter, I like to use bool.
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }

    public Task<int> GetValueAsync()
    {
        // Do Some Work
        var result = ...;

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

However, if your code is slow and you end up blocking the UI for a long period of time I would consider looking in to if you can re-write your code as actually being async or perhaps wrapping the code in to a background thread, but I would only do a background thread if it was a last resort.