# ArgumentException isn't thrown on Task.WaitAll(new Task[0])

Tags: c#, task, msdn

When I read the MSDN documentation on [`Task.WaitAll(params Task[] tasks)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) it says it throws an ArgumentException when:

> The *tasks* argument contains a null element.
>
> -or-
>
> The *tasks* argument is an empty array.

But when I call `Task.WaitAll(new Task[0]);` it passes on without any exception.

Am I misunderstanding the documentation, or is this just an error (or outdated info)?

I understand `Task.WhenAll(new Task[0])` does the same, except returning a task of course. This [feature was sometimes used to get a completed task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26737698/1380710), before [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx) was introduced in .NET 4.6.

I am actually glad that `Task.WaitAll()` seems to behave this way, so I don't have to treat an empty array as a special case, but I still want to make sure that I understood it right.

I am running my application on 4.5.2 by the way. But I just made a new solution targeted to 4.6.1 and it behaves the same way.

Comment: The documentation certainly changed between [VS 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.100).aspx) and [VS 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) - specifically it adds the `tasks argument is an empty array` text - interesting. My money is documentation error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems to be a wrong documentation. According to source code ([Can be found here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,72b6b3fa5eb35695) or via Resharper)
`ArgumentException` raised only when:

Argument is `null`:

```
5043     if (tasks == null)
5044     {
5045        throw new ArgumentNullException("tasks");
5046     }
```

Or one of array's element is `null':

```
5070    // Collects incomplete tasks in "waitedOnTaskList"
5071    for (int i = tasks.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
5072    {
5073        Task task = tasks[i];
5074
5075        if (task == null)
5076        {
5077            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Task_WaitMulti_NullTask"), "tasks");
5078        }
```

I cant find any checks for empty array in code.

PS: I was looking at .NET Framework 4.6.2 source code