# Creating a method to return Task<List<MyDataObject>> foo()

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I can solve this in .Net 4.5 but I must solve it in .Net 4.0, and so far i have not been successful.
I have not been able to get my replies into a `Task<List<MyDataObject>>`. The code below can create `List<MyDataObject>`.

```
public Task<List<MyDataObject>> Foo()
{
     IEnumerable<string> names = GetList();
     var tasks = new List<Task>();
     foreach (var name in names)
     {               tasks.Add(Task<MyDataObject>.Factory.StartNew(
               () =>
               {
                    var reply = new MyDataObject();
                    var workerObject = new WorkerObject();
                    workerObject.Foo2();
                    reply.Success = true;
                    return reply;
                }));
       }

       Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
       var replyList = new List<MyDataObject>();
       for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count(); i++)
       {     replyList.Add(((Task<MyDataObject>)tasks[i]).Result);
        }

        return replyList;
}
```

`WhenAll()` is 4.5 only

`await` is 4.5 only

so i cannot accept those

I agree that this doesnt compile. What I showed was i can iterate through the  results. However I do not know how to go from

```
List<MyDataObject>()
```

to

```
Task<List<MyDataObject>>
```

Thank you for the replies. I am going to accept Yuval Itzchakov's answer because it solves my problem in a simple manner. I am limited to no new assemblies for this use case. I would have selected 280Z28's second option had I had another method that required this functionality.

Comment: Your function should return a `Task<List<MyDataObject>>` yet you return a `List<MyDataObject>`. Without knowing about `Task`s, this looks like a compile-time issue to me.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `so far I have not been successful`? What isn't working? Please give us specifics.

Comment: It would be better to use async/await. But without that option, try this: [Creating a completed task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245968/create-a-completed-taskt)

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TaskCompletionSource<List<MyDataObject>>`

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

var replyList = new List<MyDataObject>();

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count(); i++)
{                
    replyList.Add(((Task<MyDataObject>)tasks[i]).Result);
}

var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<MyDataObject>>();
tcs.SetResult(replyList);
return tcs.Task;
```

You can also download [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) to get the 
NET 4.5 effect in .NET 4.0

Comment: Do note that to use Microsoft.Blc.Async in .NET 4.0, you will need to install KB2468871 (Update for the .NET Framework 4)

Answer (score 1):

You'll get precisely the same behavior in .NET 4.0 if you follow these steps:

#### Define a `WhenAll` method

```
public static Task<TResult[]> WhenAll<TResult>(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> tasks)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<TResult[]> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult[]>();
    Action<Task<TResult>[]> continuationAction =
        completedTasks =>
        {
            List<TResult> results = new List<TResult>();
            List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();
            bool canceled = false;

            foreach (var completedTask in completedTasks)
            {
                switch (completedTask.Status)
                {
                case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                    results.Add(completedTask.Result);
                    break;

                case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                    canceled = true;
                    break;

                case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                    exceptions.AddRange(completedTask.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unreachable");
                }
            }

            if (exceptions.Count > 0)
                taskCompletionSource.SetException(exceptions);
            else if (canceled)
                taskCompletionSource.SetCanceled();
            else
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(results.ToArray());
        };
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), continuationAction);
    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

#### Use the [`Select`](http://rackerlabs.github.io/dotnet-threading/docs-latest/html/M_Rackspace_Threading_CoreTaskExtensions_Select__2.htm) method from the [Rackspace Threading Library](https://github.com/rackerlabs/dotnet-threading/releases/latest) to return the expected results

```
public Task<List<MyDataObject>> Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<string> names = GetList();
    var tasks = new List<Task<MyDataObject>>();
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task<MyDataObject>.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                var reply = new MyDataObject();
                var workerObject = new WorkerObject();
                workerObject.Foo2();
                reply.Success = true;
                return reply;

            }));
    }

    return WhenAll(tasks).Select(result => new List<MyDataObject>(result.Result));
}
```

### Alternatively:

As an alternative, you could modify the `WhenAll` method above to return `Task<List<TResult>>` instead of `Task<TResult[]>`. This would allow you to simply use the following method.

```
public Task<List<MyDataObject>> Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<string> names = GetList();
    var tasks = new List<Task<MyDataObject>>();
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task<MyDataObject>.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                var reply = new MyDataObject();
                var workerObject = new WorkerObject();
                workerObject.Foo2();
                reply.Success = true;
                return reply;

            }));
    }

    return WhenAll(tasks);
}
```