# How to convert a Task<Tuple<E,R>> into a Task<E>

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Having my first crack at writing a TAP asynchronous implementation of a simple command-response style comms. protocol stack.

The reference synchronous implementation provides a couple of public methods

```c#
public E SendCommand(C command);
public E SendCommandAndRetrieveResponse(C command, out R response);
```

(where E is some form of error code type) that both invoke a common internal

```
E _SendCommandAndRetrieveResponse(C command, out R response);
```

passing a dummy response in the case of SendCommand().

So I'm thinking that the signature of of the equivalent asynchronous methods would be

```
public Task<E> SendCommandAsync(C command);
public Task<Tuple<E, R>> SendCommandAndRetrieveResponseAsync(C command);
```

So far so good, but whats got me stumped is if I follow the synchronous model and use a common private

```
Task<Tuple<E, R>> _SendCommandAndRetrieveResponseAsync(C command);
```

how do I convert/proxy the Task<Tuple<E, R>> returned by the private method into a Task<E> for the benefit of SendCommandAsync()?

thx

Richard.

Comment: Are you targeting .NET 4.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make it async.

```
public async Task<E> SendCommandAsync(C command)
{
    var result = await _SendCommandAndRetrieveResponseAsync(command);
    return result.Item1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Tuple` has two values, you can simply return the first one from the common private, which is `E`. This value can be used as a result for [`Task.FromResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx), which will create a completed task based on the value.

```
public Task<E> SendCommandAsync(C command)
{
    return Task.FromResult(_SendCommandAndRetrieveResponseAsync(command).Result.Item1);
}
```

*Note: This solution uses .NET 4.5 features, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4245968/1218281) question for alternate solutions instead of `FromResult`*.

Comment: Will that work? The value you are returning is `E` and not `Task<E>` in that scenario isn't it?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Your right, I'll have to make an example and try and solve this.

Comment: I believe this should be `FromResult(_SendCommandAnd..(command).Result.Item1)`. You can't access `Item1` directly there.

Comment: Isn't this implementing SendCommandAsync() as a synchronous blocking call that returns a completed task once the task returned by the underlying _SendCommandAndRetrieveResponseAsync() call has completed?   Not what I was angling for.

Comment: I believe in this case the answer is yes as it has to wait for the first task to complete before it can put the result into `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: If that is what you're after why don't you just use async/await as in Jeff's answer?

Comment: This won't work as you intend it to.  By accessing the `Result` property of the task, you're effectively making the call synchronous since it will block to wait for the result. If you're going to process the task, you need to use a continuation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ContinueWith` call to convert the Task holding the Tuple, into a Task holding just `E`. This has a side-effect of creating a nested task `Task<Task<E>>`, which can be solved by unwrapping them.

```
private Task<Tuple<E, R>> _SendCommandAndRetrieveResponseAsync(C command)
{
    Task<Tuple<E, R>> result = //.....

    return result;
}

public Task<E> SendCommandAsync(C command)
{
    return _SendCommandAndRetrieveResponseAsync(command)
        .ContinueWith(task => new TaskCompletionSource<E>(task.Result.Item1).Task)
        .Unwrap();
}
```

Comment: I *think* this is what I'm after, but won't have my code in a state to be able to try it out for a while yet.  Will be back to vote once I've seen it working.  thx